# How to find branch cut of $\ln(\sin(z))$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-cuts

I know that $\ln(z)$ is undefined when $z=0$ or $z=\inf$ , so I manged to find the critical points to be $z=\{k*\pi,\inf*i, -\inf*i\}$ , for every integer k, but I don't know how to proceed from here to find the branch cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
$$\sin(x+iy)= \sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$
Now it depends how you choose the branch cut of the logarithm, I'll pick it along the negative real axis. To find points on the branch cut, we must thus have:
$$
\sin(x)\cosh(y)<0\\
\cos(x)\sinh(y)=0
$$
The first condition gives $\sin(x)<0$. The second one gives either $y=0$ or $\cos(x)=0$. We have two cases:

1. $\sin(x)<0,\cos(x)=0$ implies $x=-\pi/2+2k\pi$. Therefore, on all verical lines $\Re(z)=-\pi/2+2k\pi$, we have a branch cut.
2. $\sin(x)<0,y=0$ defines intervals on the real axis of the form $((2k-1)\pi,2k\pi)$, giving the second branch cut condition: $z\in ((2k-1)\pi,2k\pi)$.

The whole set is then:
$$
B=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}.(\Re(z)=-\pi/2+2k\pi\,\,\lor\,\,z\in ((2k-1)\pi,2k\pi))\}
$$

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand why we choose these conditions

Comment: The branch cut is along the negative real axis, so $\Re(\sin(z))=\sin(x)\cosh(y)<0$ and $\Im(\sin(z))=\cos(x)\sinh(y)=0$ and those are the conditions.

Comment: yes, but why do we pick that the cut is along the negative axis, is that arbitrary?
I'm having a hard time visualising what's happening here

Comment: The logarithm has a branch cut, but we could also pick it along the positive real line or a ray going from the origin at an angle etc., so it is to some extent arbitrary. I just picked one option because none was specified.

Comment: okay, I think I got it: we first transform z to some other plane using sin(z), and then on this other plane we make a cut on the negative axis. so transforming back to the original one gives us the conditions

Comment: Yes, you can picture it that way. I like to just say "okay, I've got $\log(f(z))$" and $\log(\cdot)$ by itself has a branch cut on the negative reals, so that means to "hit" the branch cut I have to make $f(z)$ be a negative real number and then go from there.